# regexp_matches column without result being in array/curly braces

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to extract a # + 6 digits and place it in a new column using Postgres.

I've worked this out, but it returns results with curly braces, which I gather is the results in an array.

```
SELECT regexp_matches(input, '(#+\d\d\d\d\d\d)') as output FROM table
```

I'd like to know how to output the results without the curly braces, and if there's a better way to write the regex as well. Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend to match multiple `#` characters at the beginning? Or should the `+` match the actual plus sign in the intput

Answer (score 2):

`regexp_matches()` returns an array of all matches. You can just pick the first element of that array

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(input, '(#+\d\d\d\d\d\d)'))[1] as output 
FROM table
```

You can simplify the regex a bit by using a `\d{6}` to indicate 6 digits.

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both `regexp_match()` and `regexp_matches()` return arrays.

If you just want a particular substring, sometimes I find that `regexp_replace()` is more convenient:

```
select regexp_replace(input, '.*([0-9]{6}).*', '\1')
```